# Why take my unittests long to run using Entity Framework 4 and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: entity-framework-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a unit test performance issue when using a SQL sever 2008 database and the entity framework. This problem has some weird symptoms:

- A single unit test using the database always takes a multiple of 5 seconds + 1 second (1 second for the test). So 1, 6, 11, 16 or 21 seconds.
- Which one of those durations seems to be pure random.
- I can't pin down the problem to test setup, arrange, act, assert or tear down. Whenever the database is being used i seem to have a 'chance' of a 5 second delay.
- Problem doesn't occur when using the database instance of a colleague (~1 sec / test).
- Problem doesn't occur when using the SQL server profiler (~1 sec / test).
- Problem doesn't occur when running the unit test in debug mode.
- Problems started when migrating to Visual Studio 2012 and the agile test runner.

Some test output examples:

```
Test case 1 (hiccup occurred on test init):
4/29/2013 4:01:26 PM test init
4/29/2013 4:01:31 PM after test init
4/29/2013 4:01:31 PM before arrange
4/29/2013 4:01:32 PM before act
4/29/2013 4:01:37 PM before assert
4/29/2013 4:01:38 PM test cleanup

Test case 2 (2 hiccups occurred, 1 in act and 1 in init):
4/29/2013 4:01:26 PM test init
4/29/2013 4:01:31 PM after test init
4/29/2013 4:01:31 PM before arrange
4/29/2013 4:01:32 PM before act
4/29/2013 4:01:37 PM before assert
4/29/2013 4:01:38 PM test cleanup
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? There seems to be something wrong with my sql server instance (connection pooling?? / transaction settings??)

Answer (score 0):

Does your Db/Object context get created for each test or for each fixture?
Try moving the Db/ObjectContext creation to a fixture setup method.

Also as you say these are unit tests not integration tests cant you mock the data and do everything in memory?

Finally check you dont have some "release" only settings/connection strings which are affecting performance, i.e. debug has multiple active result sets enabled but release doesnt?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, no different 'release' only settings are found. Also, this wouldn't explain why i am the only one experiencing this problem. None of my colleagues running the same unittests have these problems.